# why firefox does not break the date?

Tags: javascript

please help break the date line on components.

https://jsfiddle.net/xwvrtLt1/2/

in chrome this worked(console display date without problem). but in FF is it not worked(console display errors)

js:

```
var checkNeedZero = function(num) { 
    if(num < 10) { num = '0' + num; };
    return num;
};             


var dateRaw = '2016-03-14 17:37:12';

var date = new Date(dateRaw),
    monthNum = checkNeedZero(date.getMonth()),
    day = checkNeedZero(date.getDate()),
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    hours = checkNeedZero(date.getHours()),
    minutes = checkNeedZero(date.getMinutes());

console.log(date);

var vv = new Date(dateRaw);
console.log(vv);
console.log('---');
```

Comment: That's probably because the format of the date string is invalid, so both browsers will treat it in an implementation specific manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format is invalid, but the two different browsers treat it differently (Chrome works around the invalid date, whereas Firefox throws an error instead).

To make it valid, you can add a `T` character between the date and the time:

```
var dateRaw = '2016-03-14T17:37:12';
```

> but I get the date in a certain format. and I can not change it

In that case, you'll need to add the `T` character with JavaScript:

```
var dateRaw = '2016-03-14 17:37:12'.replace(' ', 'T');
```

This replaces the  (blank space) character with the `T` character.

Comment: Where did you read that? The spec says something different: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format

Comment: but I get the date in a certain format. and I can not change it

Comment: @FelixKling According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), you must put a "T" between the date and time if you are using hyphens.

Comment: @stackow101: then you need to parse it yourself. Should be easy with a regular expression.

Comment: @FelixKling I have no idea where I read that, but that's certainly what I've believed for a long time! I've modified the answer with a more accurate response.

Comment: @UndoingTech—note also that MDN says "*It is not recommended to use Date.parse*".

Comment: After using this time may  be changed

Comment: @RobG Sorry, I wasn't trying to recommend using Date.parse.  I was just pointing it out since it is implicitly called when using Date().

Comment: They say not to use Date.parse (and implicitly the Date constructor), instead parse the date yourself, because of sketchy browser implementations.

Answer (score 3):

In the Date constructor they use the same mechanism as in `Date.parse(string)`, the advantage of the latter being that it doesn't throw an error for an invalid date, instead it returns `NaN`.

This link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx#Anchor_2 describes which dates are considered valid, mainly a simplified ISO8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ - which is only available for Internet Explorer 9 and above and not in quirks mode) and then an entire list of formats are tried: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx#Anchor_4

The ECMA script standard 6.0 supports the ISO8601 format: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format, but then says if this fails, specific vendor implementations can be attempted.

Bottom line: you can make the date valid by separating the date and time with a capital 'T', or you can use slashes instead of dashes.